# Is a molecular orbital the same as a state function for the single particle Hamiltonians that appear in SCF?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, condensed-matter, material-science

Amongst the self-consistent field methods, the practitioner solves a set of Schrödinger like equations for independent electrons. I have tried to understand what a molecular orbital is from the Wikipedia article, but I can't say what it is because I feel the explanation is so elaborate. But it sounds like it could be the same as a state function for the single-particle Hamiltonians that appear in SCF. Is that what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SCF one-particle wavefunctions for electron in a molecule are molecular orbitals, it is not always true that molecular orbitals are always solutions of SCF equations.

An example of SCF molecular orbitals are solutions of Kohn-Sham Schrödinger-like equations for electronic orbitals in a molecule.

An example of electronic orbitals which are not connected to SCF approximation is the case of the [Hückel Molecular Orbital theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method).